# How to read snmp table using net-snmp library?

Tags: c, snmp, net-snmp

I'm writing a simple SNMP manager using net-snmp library that for the given OID reads that object from the agent and returns it to the caller. In case of tables I need to them pack them in a structure before returning them.

So far, I can read single objects but I have no idea how to read tables. I know I can read multiple objects at once with bulk requests, but I don't know the number of table rows in advance (only columns) so I can't know what *max_repetitions* should be set to.

Is there a library function that can help with that? I looked but haven't found any. I've found this [table API](http://www.net-snmp.org/dev/agent/group__table.html), but if I understand correctly, it's for agents creating tables, not reading them.
If there isn't any convenient functions, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: Why not dig into the code of snmptable command line utility http://www.net-snmp.org/tutorial/tutorial-5/commands/snmptable.html?

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the suggestion, I haven't thought of looking at the source code of the command. I was hoping there would be some elegant solution but it seems they too must loop bulk requests until they figure out when the whole table is read with some convoluted algorithm, which I was hoping to avoid.